# What are the consequences of Xamarin iOS app swipe away

Tags: ios, xamarin, swipe

Does anyone know the consequences of swipe the app away in iOS during loading the next time? Are some resources/assemblies/xaml/styles cached to be reused the next launch? I have an impression that something is locking the app when I swipe it away a few times in turn and launch - only certain simple forms are loaded correctly. How is memory released? After some time?

Comment: are you talking about closing the app via the app switching mechanism?

Comment: Testing on simulator, or on an actual device - if so, which device?  I've never seen an issue related to swipe-killing an app, and then launching it again from home screen. It starts again from scratch. If you are seeing a problem, then (IMHO) something about your app startup is not reliable - some timing issue, depending on exactly what happens when. Often this can be improved by creating a simple "launch" screen that your app starts on: `MainPage = new LaunchScreen();`. While that screen is up, you do any needed data loading, then switch to your actual main page.

Comment: Pretty sure the app itself is stable, but the OS notices if it's getting killed a lot and may de-prioritise some functions (like maybe registering for APNS).  So you may want to review your launch path and see if something depends on an OS provided service to launch properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes I am talking about switching mechanism. To narrow down the problem  - this seems to affect only certain views - by my intuition those with large xaml and invoked as modal. I will keep investigating but my job looks like testing blackbox which answers randomly to the same conditions. Thank you anyway - I will inspect both suggestions.